# How to send a file to the ActiveMQ Queue?

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I have a simple Apache Camel route in JBoss FUSE:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <bean id="startPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.routepolicy.quartz.CronScheduledRoutePolicy">
        <property name="routeStartTime" value="*/3 * * * * ?"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
        <property name="userName" value="admin" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean> 

    <camelContext id="blueprintContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
          <route id="testRoute" routePolicyRef="startPolicy" autoStartup="false">
            <from uri="activemq:source-queue?username=admin&amp;password=admin"></from>
            <log message="${body}" loggingLevel="INFO"></log>
            <to uri="activemq:sink-queue?username=admin&amp;password=admin"></to>
        </route>    
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

I can connect to the ActiveMQ broker and send a message to the queue, by using this standalone client:

```
public class MessageSender {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = 
                new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

        factory.setUserName("admin");
        factory.setPassword("admin");

        Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
        try {
          Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
          Queue queue = session.createQueue("source-queue");

          MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
          Message message = session.createTextMessage("some message to queue...");

          producer.send(message);

        } finally {
          connection.close();
        }       
    }
}
```

From the logs I see, that messages is consumed from the queue and message bodies are displays in the log:

[image]

How to send a file to the ActiveMQ Queue? For example, I have a simple form with `<input type="file">` encoded in `multipart/form-data`. By using this form I need to send a payload of POST request to the ActiveMQ Queue.

How can I do that?

I would be very grateful for the information.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Well, once you have the payload, convert it to a byte or string and send it to the your activemq endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Mary Zheng](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/author/mary-zheng) provided an excellent example, how it may be done:

[ActiveMQ File Transfer Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jms/apache-activemq-file-transfer-example)

Method of class `QueueMessageProducer`, that sends the file message to ActiveMQ Broker:

```
private void sendFileAsBytesMessage(File file) throws JMSException, IOException {
    BytesMessage bytesMessage = session.createBytesMessage();
    bytesMessage.setStringProperty("fileName", file.getName());
    bytesMessage.writeBytes(fileManager.readfileAsBytes(file));

    msgProducer.send(bytesMessage);
}
```

, where:

```
ConnectionFactory connFactory = 
    new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(username, password, activeMqBrokerUri);
Connection connection = connFactory.createConnection();
ActiveMQSession session = 
    (ActiveMQSession) connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

`FileAsByteArrayManager` class that performs a low-level operations with files:

```
public class FileAsByteArrayManager {

    public byte[] readfileAsBytes(File file) throws IOException {    
        try (RandomAccessFile accessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) accessFile.length()];
            accessFile.readFully(bytes);
            return bytes;
        }
    }

    public void writeFile(byte[] bytes, String fileName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try (RandomAccessFile accessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")) {
            accessFile.write(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```